# How to search and replace the specific line number string

Tags: shell, replace, sed

```
line_index="2d";

file="./Desktop/books.sh";

sed -i.bak -e $line_index $file
```

Will delete the entire line that $line_index is pointing to

```
sed -i "s/harry/potter/g" $file
```

will search for harry and replace with potter

Is there anyway that i can combine both statement so it will only replace the specific line number of harry instead of all the harry in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, "addresses" and "commands" can be freely combined:

```
sed '2s/harry/potter/g'
```

Comment: @Justpee: "Thanks" on StackOverflow = upvote/accept :-)

Answer (score 1):

To restrict substitution to a line number, add it before the command:

```
sed -i "2s/harry/potter/" $file
```